# Writing multiple regex pattern to parse HTML

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-match

I'm fetching an HTML webpage with `file_get_contents()`, I get a table like below, there are more than 150 rows:

```
<tr class="tabrow ">
    <td class="tabcol  tdmin_2l">FIRST+DATA</td>
    <td class="tabcol">
        <a class="modal-button" title="SECOND+DATA"  href="THIRD+DATA" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 800, y: 640}, overlayOpacity: 0.9, classWindow: 'phocamaps-plugin-window', classOverlay: 'phocamaps-plugin-overlay'}">
            asdxxx
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="tabcol"></td>
    <td class="tabcol">FOURTH+DATA</td>
</tr>
```

I want to get the `FIRST DATA`, `SECOND DATA`, `THIRD DATA` and `FOURTH DATA` with a `preg_match_all()` call. I tried to write multiple patterns, but I couldn't succeed. Here's what I tried:

```
preg_match_all('/(<td class="tabcol  tdmin_2l">|title=")(.*?)(<\/td>|")/s', $raw, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

What's the true patterns?

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex.

Comment: Use a DOM parser instead. Parsing HTML markup with a regular expression is very unreliable. It will break the moment some minor change is done to the markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str = <<<HTML
<tr class="tabrow ">
<td class="tabcol  tdmin_2l">FIRST+DATA</td>
<td class="tabcol"><a class="modal-button" title="SECOND+DATA"  href="THIRD+DATA" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 800, y: 640}, overlayOpacity: 0.9, classWindow: 'phocamaps-plugin-window', classOverlay: 'phocamaps-plugin-overlay'}">asdxxx</a></td>
<td class="tabcol"></td>
<td class="tabcol">FOURTH+DATA</td>
</tr>
HTML;

preg_match_all('/<td[^>]*>(.*?)<\/td>/im', $str, $td_matches);
preg_match('/ title="([^"]*)"/i', $td_matches[1][1], $title);
preg_match('/ href="([^"]*)"/i', $td_matches[1][1], $href);

echo $td_matches[1][0] . "\n";
echo $title[1] . "\n";
echo $href[1] . "\n";
echo $td_matches[1][3];
```

Comment: thanks, this is not bad but looks like some modifications in regex pattern, because second and third datas are combined in this pattern.

Comment: I didn't understand at first, is it better like this?

Comment: thanks, i made some modifications and now it works good!

Answer (score 3):

It does not answer your question directly, but it's the correct way to go.

You should avoid parsing HTML/XML content with regular expressions. Wonder why?

> Entire HTML parsing is not possible with regular expressions, since it depends on matching the opening and the closing tag which is not possible with regexps.
>
> Regular expressions can only match regular languages but HTML is a context-free language. The only thing you can do with regexps on HTML is heuristics but that will not work on every condition. It should be possible to present a HTML file that will be matched wrongly by any regular expression.
>
> *— https://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/65732*

Use a [DOM parser](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) instead. Here's a glimpse of what it's like:

```
composer require symfony/dom-crawler symfony/css-selector
```

```php
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$html = <<<HTML
<tr class="tabrow ">
<td class="tabcol  tdmin_2l">FIRST+DATA</td>
<td class="tabcol"><a class="modal-button" title="SECOND+DATA"  href="THIRD+DATA" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 800, y: 640}, overlayOpacity: 0.9, classWindow: 'phocamaps-plugin-window', classOverlay: 'phocamaps-plugin-overlay'}">asdxxx</a></td>
<td class="tabcol"></td>
<td class="tabcol">FOURTH+DATA</td>
</tr>
HTML;

$crawler = new Crawler($html);

$first  = $crawler->filter('.tabcol.tdmin_2l')->text();
$second = $crawler->filter('.tabcol:nth-child(2) a')->attr('title');
$third  = $crawler->filter('.tabcol:nth-child(2) a')->attr('href');
$fourth = $crawler->filter('.tabcol:nth-child(4)')->text();

var_dump($first, $second, $third, $fourth);
// Outputs:
// string(10) "FIRST+DATA"
// string(11) "SECOND+DATA"
// string(10) "THIRD+DATA"
// string(11) "FOURTH+DATA"
```

Easier and cleaner, right?

Using such parsers, you have the ability to extract elements using XPath as well.

Comment: I like this solution, but are you sure it finds 2nd and 3rd in the "title" and "href" attributes?

Comment: @fafl: Now I'm sure it does.